boost spirit alternative operator
Please advise about boost spirit alternative operator.
test_parser() is posted on the official website.
test_parser("Hello", string("Hell") | string("Hello"));

Output
fail

I think that string("Hell") is fail ,then next step
try
string("Hello") is OK

Thank you for your reply.
Although string("Hell") is partial match, the evaluation result is true, so string("Hello") is never evaluated.
Is the above interpretation correct?

The documentation example is different: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_86_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/operator/alternative.html#spirit.qi.reference.operator.alternative.example
test_parser("Hello", string("Hello") | int_);
test_parser("123", string("Hello") | int_);

In short, a | b ONLY EVER parses b IFF a fails. The reason for this is that a PEG (Parser Expression Grammar) parses left-to-right greedy. This is documented here: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_86_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/abstracts/parsing_expression_grammar.html (Note the link to Difference parsers).
So in your example string("Hello") will never match, because it would always have matched string("Hell") first. Re-ordering them helps:
test_parser("Hello", qi::string("Hell") | qi::string("Hello")); 
test_parser("Hello", qi::string("Hello") | qi::string("Hell")); 

Prints
Matched: Hell
Matched: Hello

You can also consider qi::symbols which will automatically trie elements in such an order that the longest possible match is found:
Live On Coliru
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

template <typename Expr> void test_parser(std::string_view input, Expr const& parser) {
    std::string result;
    if (qi::parse(input.begin(), input.end(), parser, result)) {
        std::cout << "Matched: " << result << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "Failed to match" << std::endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    test_parser("Hello", qi::string("Hell") | qi::string("Hello")); 
    test_parser("Hello", qi::string("Hello") | qi::string("Hell")); 

    std::cout << "\nUsing symbols" << std::endl;
    qi::symbols<char, std::string> sym;
    sym.add("Hello", "Hello");
    sym.add("World", "World");
    sym.add("Hell", "Hell");
    sym.add("Wor", "Wor");

    test_parser("Hell", sym);
    test_parser("Hello", sym);
    test_parser("World", sym);
    test_parser("Wor", sym);
    test_parser("Worst", sym);
}

Printing
Matched: Hell
Matched: Hello

Using symbols
Matched: Hell
Matched: Hello
Matched: World
Matched: Wor
Matched: Wor

